# Traffic routed to br0 ends up on loopback

Tags: routing

I'm trying to route traffic to 10.2.129.0/24 via 'br0', but it ends up at 'lo' instead. 
Any idea where it goes wrong?

```
# ip route show
default via 192.168.2.1 dev eth0
10.2.129.0/24 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.2.129.8
192.168.2.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.210
224.0.0.0/4 dev br0  scope link

# ping 10.2.129.1
PING 10.2.129.1 (10.2.129.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.2.129.8 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.2.129.8 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.2.129.8 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable

# tshark -i br0 -f 'icmp'
Capturing on 'br0'
0 packets captured

# tshark -i lo -f 'icmp'
Capturing on 'Loopback'
1   0.000000   10.2.129.8 -> 10.2.129.8   ICMP 126 Destination unreachable (Host unreachable)
2   0.000541   10.2.129.8 -> 10.2.129.8   ICMP 126 Destination unreachable (Host unreachable)
3   0.001093   10.2.129.8 -> 10.2.129.8   ICMP 126 Destination unreachable (Host unreachable)
3 packets captured
```

Answer (score 1):

The messages from `10.2.129.8` are not responses to the pings, but messages from your local host telling that it can't send the pings to `10.2.129.1`.